# How to pop elements from another function's kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I have a function that is responsible for getting data from the `kwargs` of several other functions.

The other functions pass their own kwargs to this function along with a `keep` argument that determines whether or not to keep these properties in the kwargs - i.e. whether to use `get` or `pop`.

```py
def _handle_kwargs(keep, **kwargs):
    # keep: whether to keep the kwarg when we're done with it (i.e. get or pop)
    if keep: func = getattr(kwargs, 'get')
    else: func = getattr(kwargs, 'pop')

    # get or pop some kwargs individually
    debug = func('debug', False)
    assert isinstance(debug, bool)
    ...
    # repeated for several different possible kwargs
    return debug, some_other_kwarg, ...

def normal_function(**kwargs)
    debug, some_other_kwarg = _handle_kwargs(False, **kwargs)
```

Getting the values from the kwargs works fine. However, if I try to `pop` the kwargs, then they are still present in the original function's `kwargs`. I suspect this is because `_handle_kwargs` is only modifying its own kwargs.

How can I ensure that the kwargs are removed if I use `pop`, even if that's coming from another function?

Comment: Just pass the `kwargs` as the plain `dict` object, then it will work. When you splat it into `_handle_kwargs`, it creates a new dict object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can do that passing to **kwargs, as it appears to be passed by value, but if it's ok to modify the inner function, you could pass kwargs as a plain dictionary, i.e. without the `**`.

```
def test(x):
    print(x)
    x.pop('test')
    print(x)

def real(**kwargs):
    test(kwargs)
    print(kwargs)

real(test='nothing', real='something')
```

Output

```
{'test': 'nothing', 'real': 'something'}
{'real': 'something'}
{'real': 'something'}
```

Comment: Things aren't passed by value in Python, everything is call by sharing. However, the `**kwargs` syntax creates a *new dictionary* on each call, so it looks like call by value. But really it's just syntactic sugar for constructing and passing a dict object. I only mention this because saying "call by value" and "call by sharing" adds a lot of confusion. Python does *neither*. But your answer is essentially correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and it is quite welcome. One of the reasons I like to answer questions on SO is just this, to refine my knowledge further which I'd never get from being a passive observer.

Comment: I *meant* to say that "call by value" and "call by reference" are confusing, because Python uses neither, it uses ["call by sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

Comment: After doing some googling I see there is a lot of controversy on the topic, but the main distinction between CBR and CBS seems to be that references to variables can't be passed, just to objects. This suddenly reminded me of an old FORTRAN compiler I used to work with that would pass constants by reference, allowing the unfortunate programmer to change the value of 0, 1 or any other number passed to a subroutine, which would subsequently cause all kinds of mayhem.

Comment: I think it's straightforward. The distinction is that in CBR, assignments to the parameter are seen *in the caller*. So, for example, you can write a function (with made up syntax) `def swap(&a, &b)`. Then: `a = 1; b = 2; swap(a, b); print(a, b)` would print `2, 1`. you can't do that in python.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't pass a dictionary to `_handle_kwargs`. The **kwargs syntax when calling a function actually "explodes" kwargs.

That is, if kwargs is {'a':1, 'b':2}, then `_handle_kwargs(False, **kwargs)` is equivalent to `_handle_kwargs(False, kwargs['a'], kwargs['b'])`. You don't pass the `kwargs` dict at all!

`_handle_kwargs` collects them into a new dictionary, so it won't affect the original one.

The solution is very simple.

First, `def _handle_kwargs(keep, kwargs):` without asterisks. Just receive a dict.
Second, call it like so:

```
def normal_function(**kwargs)
    debug, some_other_kwarg = _handle_kwargs(False, kwargs)
```

See the second line - calling `_handle_kwargs` without asterisks - just pass the dict.